# Control Image Quality in Signature

Tags: itext

I am having a problem with iText where the image I am trying to append to a layer within a digital signature appearance (PdfSignatureAppearance) is coming out blurry.
I have tried adding scaling to the image and also removing scaling, but the results seem inconsistent.

I noticed a similar problem mentioned here:
http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/JPEG-images-become-blurry-when-added-to-a-document-td2143785.html

Scaling to fit the margins of the field:

```
    if (i1.getWidth() > 180 || i1.getHeight() > 50) {
        i1.scaleToFit(180, 50);
    }
```

Scaling down to try to increase quality:

```
    i1.scalePercent(85f);
```

-Thanks

Comment: iText doesn't change the pixel size of the image, so if you add an image with a limited number of pixels and you scale it to make it bigger, than it will be blurry. Provide an image with more pixels to fix this.

Comment: I found that further scaling of the image down to 65% helped for some reason.
It looked much better than 70, 75, 80, or 85%.